# Return hello world to olleh dlrow in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function, reverse

Was wondering if you can reverse a string and still maintain the order.

Below is a function that returns **"dlroW olleH"** and I want to return **"olleH dlroW"**

```
var myFunction = function() {
var userdata = document.getElementById('data').value,
    uRev = userdata.split("").reverse().join("");
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = uRev;
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: @JamesDonnelly That question is about reversing the whole string, not one word at a time. See the duplicate I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the words and then the characters:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    var userdata = document.getElementById('data').value,
    uRev = userdata.split(" ").reverse().join(" ").split("").reverse().join("");
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = uRev;
};
```

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WvSWL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function reverseString(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}

function reverseEachWord(s) {
    return s.split(" ").map(reverseString).join(" ");
```

Comment: Didn't see your answer :) lost between all the others. The other answers reverse the order of the words, then the string (Hello World -> World Hello -> olleH dlroW). This version reverses each individual word. It might be better suited.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(userdata.split(" ").reverse().join(" ").split("").reverse().join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

first split your string in an array of words using `split(" ")`, then split each array segment using the method above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var myFunction = function() {
    var resArr=[];
    var userdata = document.getElementById('data').value,
    uRev = userdata.split("");
    for (var i=0;i<uRev.length;i++){
      resArr.push(uRev[i].reverse());
    }

    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = resArr.join('');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = 'Hello World';

alert( 
    test.replace(
        /\w+/g , 
        function(a){return a.split('').reverse().join('');}
    )
);
```